# How to Auto Post to Google Plus in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, google-plus

i want post in my google pluse page  when i create or post something new in my website (php) .

recently i search in google api but cant find something good stuff .

share if you have done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Google+ APIs do not provide a way for you to programmatically post to your Page from your site. You can use one of the [Third Party management tools](http://www.google.com/+/business/3rdpartytools.html) that Google+ has worked with to provide additional options.

Answer (score 2):

Google+ does not officially allow auto-posting. There are some third party service providers like Hootsuite and there are some third party APIs like http://www.nextscripts.com/google-plus-automated-posting

Answer (score -1):

Here's a plugin which claims to let you post to Google+.

http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/google-plus-authorship

**Edit:** Turns out this plugin does not post to Google+ as was meant by the asker. Move along.

Comment: thanks , but i need to core php or cake php , i will try to get code from this plugin :)

Comment: @YogeshSaroya You have tagged the question wrong, if it isn't Wordpress.

Comment: @noc2spam The original question title had Wordpress in it as well - I look like a goofball now.

Comment: Lol @NicholasPickering I can understand that. That is why I commented here :-)

Comment: lol am I getting downvoted because the question is no longer Wordpress? That's just silly.

Comment: The plugin doesn't post in the manner that they are asking about.